# `co` exception causes Node Promise `reject()` to throw in Jetbrains debugger

Tags: node.js, promise, v8, es6-promise, jetbrains-ide

I run fairly complex piece of code in Node 6.x, and I'm unable to replicate the problem in simple conditions. The gist of the relevant part of the app is

```
// app.js
someCoWrapper(function*() {
    yield hapiServerStart();
    // unreachable
    ...
})
.catch(console.error);
```

---

```
// some-co-wrapper.js

function someCoWrapper(genFn) {
    return co(genFn).then(
        (result) => new Promise((resolve) => resolve(result)),
        (error) => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                return reject(error)
            })
        }
    )
}
```

---

```
// some-callback-called-inside-serverStart.js

...
assert(..., 'I was thrown from server init callback');
...
```

The wrapper for `co` was there to switch between promise implementations, and it was meant to be transparent (it failed).

Here I expect `co` promise to catch an exception from generator and log it to `console.error`. This works as expected with `node debug app.js`. In Jetbrains (PhpStorm 2016), it works with *Run*. But it throws an uncaught exception with `Debug`, call stack is really obscure:

[image: Broken promise]

The problem doesn't occur when `yield hapiServerStart();` is secured with `try...catch` (naturally).

Changing `Promise` implementation helps, both

```
global.Promise = require('es6-promise').Promise;
```

and

```
global.Promise = require('bluebird');
```

work. And the most interesting thing is that changing the code above to

```
return co(genFn)
.then(
    (result) => Promise.resolve(result)),
    (error) => Promise.reject(error))
);
```

helps, too!

Too many moving parts are there, and the fact that it occurs in Jetbrains product suggests that there may be something fishy with it.

I would be grateful for any comments that may shed some light on what happens here.

And the real quesion is how `new Promise((err) => reject(err))` differs from `Promise.reject(err)` in Node/V8 implementation? Is there something that may cause it to misbehave on some conditions (not just in debugger but in production)?

Comment: Can only agree, it certainly looks a bit fishy. Simplest form of coercion to `Promise` would be `function someCoWrapper(genFn) {
 return Promise.resolve(co(genFn));
}`. How does that behave?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Sure, this works fine as well. Something happens in native Promise constructor, I guess.